# Oracle 10gR2 slow query with exists

Tags: sql, oracle, query-optimization

i'm new in Oracle.
I writed a query that takes about 40s

```
SELECT count(*) FROM (
 SELECT * FROM (SELECT r.idra FROM hm.Ra r 
       WHERE (r.rxdate BETWEEN to_date('2013-09-01','YYYY-MM-DD') and to_date('2013-11-01','YYYY-MM-DD')) 
and (r.idstato IN (1,2,3,4,5,6)) 
and ((r.idgruppo IN (864,863...,595))  
      or (r.curridgroup IN (864,863...,595)) 
      or (EXISTS (SELECT rev.idra FROM hm.Raevent rev WHERE rev.idra = r.idra AND rev.idgroup IS NOT NULL AND rev.idgroup IN (864,863...,595)))  ) ) ) r1
```

After search a little bit, i rewrited the query with an inner join, and it take about 1s:

```
select count(*)
FROM
(SELECT r.idra FROM hm.v_Ra r 
 WHERE (r.rxdate BETWEEN to_date('2013-09-01','YYYY-MM-DD') and to_date('2013-11-01','YYYY-MM-DD')) 
and (r.idstato IN (1,2,3,4,5,6)))  rd
inner join 
((SELECT idra FROM hm.Ra r
WHERE  ((r.idgruppo IN (864,863...,595)) 
       or (r.curridgroup IN (864,863...,595))) 
UNION
SELECT rev.idra FROM hm.Raevent rev WHERE  rev.idgroup IS NOT NULL 
        AND rev.idgroup IN (864,863...,595) 
)) rr on rr.idra = rd.idra
```

My question is: why oracle (version 10gr2) cannot optimize the first one?
Also, is there another (faster) way to write the same query?

NB: The list (864,863...,595) has approx 30 elements, i writed 3 for convenience.
"Ra" is the parent table, and has about 150k rows, index on rxdate,idgruppo,curridgroup,idstato.
"Raevent" is a the child table and has 180k rows, index on (idra,idgroup), idgroup.

I run the sql analyzer, and on both query it gave me no advice.

Comment: Could it be that it is your union that is speeding up things? OR tends to be bad for performance.

Comment: Probably, but i cannot understand why oracle cannot optimize the "exists" in this case. The index on idra and idgroup exists, and the query optimizer should use it...

Comment: OR statements tend to cause indices not to be used, even when you would expect them to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clear question with good information, great!

You are running probably into problems with the optimizing of OR-clauses. This is a known limitation which goes back to Oracle 6 causing problems with the rule-based optimizer. I've made a number of notes on the query to help you.

First of all, always write your query in a readable format that identifies the structure to humans. The parser doesn't care how it is laid out, but humans do :-)

I've grown accustomed to the old Oracle QMS / CDM style with some additions. This style also reflects experiences from software engineering research done by IBM and information ergonomics. Essentially the query gets written down in a vertically stretching format, with vertical columns and the use of lowercase, since lowercase always the human mind to easier identify text (compare with eyes almost closed: 'PERSONEELSDOSSIER' versus 'Personeelsdossier'). After rewriting for layout the query is:

```
select count (*)
from   ( select *
         from   ( select r.idra
                  from   hm.ra r
                  where  r.rxdate between to_date ('2013-09-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd') and to_date ('2013-11-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd')
                  and    r.idstato in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
                  and    ( r.idgruppo in (864, 863...,595)
                           or r.curridgroup in (864, 863..., 595)
                           or ( exists 
                                ( select rev.idra 
                                  from   hm.raevent rev 
                                  where  rev.idra = r.idra 
                                  and    rev.idgroup is not null 
                                  and rev.idgroup in (864, 863..., 595)
                                )
                              )  
                         ) 
                ) 
       ) r
```

Then you can a number of suggestions to improve performance:

```
select count (*)
from   ( select 1 /* Note 1. */
         from   ( select r.idra /* Note 2. */
                  from   hm.ra r
                  where  r.rxdate between to_date ('2013-09-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd') and to_date ('2013-11-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd') /* Note 3. */
                  and    r.idstato in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
                  and    ( r.idgruppo in (864, 863...,595)
                           or r.curridgroup in (864, 863..., 595) /* Note 6. */
                           or ( exists /* Note 5. */
                                ( select 1 /* Note 4. */
                                  from   hm.raevent rev 
                                  where  rev.idra = r.idra 
                                  and    rev.idgroup is not null 
                                  and    rev.idgroup in (864, 863..., 595)
                                )
                              )  
                         ) 
                ) 
       ) r
```

The suggestions are:

1. Note 1: fetching all columns may cause a full table scan to occur, but you only need the count which can often be done using a small index on a required field. Note that Oracle does not store null values in an index, which is different from SQL Server.
2. Note 2: fold the query into the outside level and change r.idra to 1 again. Unnecessary nesting makes it harder to parse and after some time Oracle just stops parsing and chooses the best found execution plan so far.
3. Note 3: Using a between on a date is done well, it allows the use of an index. Check that there is an index for hm.ra.rxdate on this very restrictive date range.
4. Note 4: see change 1, but now for one column.
5. Note 5: consider the use of an IN instead of EXISTS. IN may be faster with large volumes in the table but low volume output since it does not correlate the subquery with the outside query.
6. Note 6: always try to rewrite OR into UNION or UNION ALL. OR optimilisation is not always possible. When using OR always check that the clauses are of the same type (A=1 OR A=2 OR A=3). When you have different clauses being OR-ed, the use of an index will be obsoleted and Oracle optimizer will revert to full table scans which can take a lot more time and may also purge your database cache completely effectively hindering all other users in an interactive system.

The resulting query might be:

```
select sum(c)
from   ( select count(*) c
         from   hm.ra r
         where  r.rxdate between to_date ('2013-09-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd') and to_date ('2013-11-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd')
         and    r.idstato in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
         and    r.idgruppo in (864, 863...,595)
         union all
         select count(*) c
         from   hm.ra r
         where  r.rxdate between to_date ('2013-09-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd') and to_date ('2013-11-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd')
         and    r.idstato in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
         and    r.curridgroup in (864, 863..., 595)
         union all
         select count(*) c
         from   hm.ra r
         where  r.rxdate between to_date ('2013-09-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd') and to_date ('2013-11-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd')
         and    r.idstato in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
         and    r.idra 
                in /* Use exists when used interactively in a screen. */
                ( select distinct rev.idra
                  from   hm.raevent rev 
                  where  rev.idgroup in (864, 863..., 595)
                )
       )
```

Comment: If there is a match in multiple sections (e.g. idgruppo = curridgroup), wouldn't this cause the record to be counted two or three times?

Comment: Very thanks for point me out the problem.
Oracle translates the "idgroup in (123,123,...)" in a sequence of OR clause. These conditions, combined with the "exists" lead to poor query performance.

Comment: Very thanks for point me out the problem and for the general advices.
Oracle translates the "idgroup in (123,123,...)" in a sequence of OR clause. These conditions, combined with the "exists" lead to poor query performance.

I take your query and modified a little bit (it doesn't output correctly because count 1+ the same row, because some rows has idgroup=curridgroup, as Sam said...), and the performance (1.5s) are quite comparable to the second version (1s).

Thanks again!

Comment: Happy to help you. Sam is correct, I overlooked that one and of course didn't test it on a sample first. For the sum to be correct and to not double count specific rows it is better to do a sum(*) from (select id...union <no all>select id...union <no all>select id) or something alike.